# How to sign MIDlet in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I am working on J2ME project.i am  facing one problem  regarding sign to MIDlet.please provide me step-by-step info how to sign MIDlet in J2ME and how to generate KeyStore.
i  try myself to create Keystore then it give error.

**Error:-**

```
javax.microedition.pki.CertificateException: Certificate was signed using an unsupported algorithm
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Signing a MIDlet only makes sense if you use a certificate from Thawte or Verisign. In other words, you need to pay $300 each year to have your MIDlet signed.
You cannot sign a MIDlet with your own certificate. At least, if you can, it won't actually help you. Your app will still give the security popups like "App wants to access Internet. Allow this?" and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response  i am using Https://  webservice so i need certificate for signing ?

Comment: Well, I don't have any experience with that, but afaik you just have to point your phone browser to the `.cer` file, or copy the `.cer` file to the phone storage card and click it from there. Then it will install the certificate.
Afaik the https protocol is then handled automatically by the device, and nothing for you to worry about in your MIDlet.
But not all phones allow you to install your own certificates like that.